# Form in the Epicor ERP environment

Tags: c#, beginner, winforms

I've written this code for use on a form in the Epicor ERP environment. The code is doing what I need, but since I'm still learning I would imagine that there are better ways of coding. I'm here looking for feedback to help my growth.

Example: "I see you're naming your button epiButtonC1, but a better practice would be to call it {x} for {y} reason"

Or, "You shold wrap your {x} call in a conditional statement in case {y} for {z} reason"

```
/*
******************************************************
Created: DM 3/16/2024
Custom code for non-updatable dashboard
Provides a button to launch warehouse bin search dialog,
calls grid refresh after bin selection or manual entry
******************************************************
*/
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Ice.BO;
using Ice.UI;
using Ice.Lib;
using Ice.Adapters;
using Ice.Lib.Customization;
using Ice.Lib.ExtendedProps;
using Ice.Lib.Framework;
using Ice.Lib.Searches;
using Ice.UI.FormFunctions;

public class Script
{
    // Declare script variables
    EpiTextBox myWhseBinSearchTextBox = null;

    public void InitializeCustomCode()
    {
        // Custom button to perform an action
        epiButtonC1.Click += new EventHandler(epiButtonC1_Click);

        // Dashboard tracker's "txtWhseBin_BinNum" textbox, using GUID
        myWhseBinSearchTextBox = (EpiTextBox)csm.GetNativeControlReference("01251283-1be9-4b2c-9b6f-ba18e3a76fdb");

        // When manual entry and 'tab', perform an action
        myWhseBinSearchTextBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(myWhseBinSearchTextBox_KeyDown);
    }

    public void DestroyCustomCode()
    {
        epiButtonC1.Click += new EventHandler(epiButtonC1_Click);
        myWhseBinSearchTextBox = (EpiTextBox)csm.GetNativeControlReference("01251283-1be9-4b2c-9b6f-ba18e3a76fdb");
        myWhseBinSearchTextBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(myWhseBinSearchTextBox_KeyDown);
    }

    private void SearchOnWhseBinAdapterShowDialog()
    {
        /*
        Displays Warehouse Bin search dialog box for bin selection
        */
        bool recSelected;
        string whereClause = string.Empty;
        System.Data.DataSet dsWhseBinAdapter = Ice.UI.FormFunctions.SearchFunctions.listLookup(this.oTrans, "WhseBinAdapter", out recSelected, true, whereClause);
        if (recSelected)
        {
            System.Data.DataRow adapterRow = dsWhseBinAdapter.Tables[0].Rows[0];
            if (adapterRow != null)
            {
                myWhseBinSearchTextBox.Text = adapterRow["BinNum"].ToString();
                
                // After search box selection, refresh the grid
                if(myWhseBinSearchTextBox.Text != null)
                {
                    RefreshForm();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void epiButtonC1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchOnWhseBinAdapterShowDialog();
    }

    private void myWhseBinSearchTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check if the 'TAB' key is pressed and there's text in the TextBox
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(myWhseBinSearchTextBox.Text))
        {
            // Prevent the default 'TAB' behavior for focusing the next control
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    
            // Refresh the form
            RefreshForm();
        }
    }

    private void RefreshForm()
    {           
        MainController.AppControlPanel.HandleToolClick("RefreshTool", new 
        Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ToolClickEventArgs(MainController.MainToolManager.Tools["RefreshTool"], null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome @DaShMa to CodeReview! From what perspective are you expecting a review?

Comment: @PeterCsala, I don't know what I don't know. While my code may work now, perhaps I'm leaving some gaps that will allow errors in the future. I'm looking for feedback to help me learn and grow so that my code is more robust.

Comment: @DaShMa There are [quality attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_system_quality_attributes) (like maintainability, efficiency or testability) which evaluates system/module/code from a certain angel. You have mentioned robustness. Are there any other quality attributes that you are interested?

Comment: @PeterCsala, Thanks for the link. I'm sure I'll gradually learn more about these, but for now I'm hoping for a quick review from seasoned developers that can offer some helpful tidbits. Much like you're doing now, but with a bit more specificity from the code provided.

Comment: Are the `InitializeCustomCode` and `DestroyCustomCode` the same???

Comment: Yes. Per Epicor's suggestion whatever is created should be destroyed. I've tried to mimic their provided examples, but I may not be destroying the code properly.

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick shot here

```
public void DestroyCustomCode()
{
    epiButtonC1.Click += new EventHandler(epiButtonC1_Click);
    myWhseBinSearchTextBox = (EpiTextBox)csm.GetNativeControlReference("01251283-1be9-4b2c-9b6f-ba18e3a76fdb");
    myWhseBinSearchTextBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(myWhseBinSearchTextBox_KeyDown);
}
```

You are basically assigning the eventhandlers again which can lead to not properly disposing of the object.
Change it to

```
public void DestroyCustomCode()
{
    epiButtonC1.Click -= new EventHandler(epiButtonC1_Click);
    myWhseBinSearchTextBox = (EpiTextBox)csm.GetNativeControlReference("01251283-1be9-4b2c-9b6f-ba18e3a76fdb");
    myWhseBinSearchTextBox.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(myWhseBinSearchTextBox_KeyDown);
}
```

to fix it.

In `SearchOnWhseBinAdapterShowDialog` you could return early by checking if `reSelected` is `false` which saves you one level of indentation like so

```
private void SearchOnWhseBinAdapterShowDialog()
{
    /*
    Displays Warehouse Bin search dialog box for bin selection
    */
    bool recSelected;
    string whereClause = string.Empty;
    System.Data.DataSet dsWhseBinAdapter = Ice.UI.FormFunctions.SearchFunctions.listLookup(this.oTrans, "WhseBinAdapter", out recSelected, true, whereClause);
    if (!recSelected) { return; }

    System.Data.DataRow adapterRow = dsWhseBinAdapter.Tables[0].Rows[0];
    if (adapterRow != null)
    {
        myWhseBinSearchTextBox.Text = adapterRow["BinNum"].ToString();
        
        // After search box selection, refresh the grid
        if(myWhseBinSearchTextBox.Text != null)
        {
            RefreshForm();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment! I did not understand the custom code destruction method, but after reviewing your suggestion it makes more sense now. Your suggestion for recSelected is also brilliant. I enjoy learning about these little improvements so that my code executes better.

Answer (score 3):

If the service provider has some pre-defined abstractions for some features (like `destroy` or `initialize`) then you should use those abstractions on your code. Otherwise, you would need to depend on .NET built-in features.

For instance, `InitializeCustomCode` and `DestroyCustomCode` I wouldn't suggest to expose them or use them like that unless the `Epicor` platform was built that way, and has some contracts that implement them. Because you can make `InitializeCustomCode` private and call it in the constructor, which would initialize the required components when a new instance is initiated. and for `DestroyCustomCode` we could use `IDisposable` interface, and then implement the destructor method that calls `Dispose` method to be called automatically when the instance's execution scope is finished.

Another point here is that code is mixing between UI and business logic. You can implement a service class that would expose a search method that handles `SearchOnWhseBinAdapterShowDialog` logic, and then recall that service instead.

example :

```
public sealed class WarehouseSearchService
{
    private const string BinGuid = "01251283-1be9-4b2c-9b6f-ba18e3a76fdb";
    private const string WhseBinAdapter = "WhseBinAdapter";
    
    // expose this method to the consumer
    public string GetBinNumber()
    {
        if(TryGetWhseBinAdapter(string.Empty, out System.Data.DataSet dsWhseBinAdapter))
        {
            System.Data.DataRow adapterRow = dsWhseBinAdapter.Tables[0].Rows[0];            
            return adapterRow["BinNum"]?.ToString();            
        }
        
        return null;    
    }
    
    // generalize this method so it can be reused internally.
    private bool TryGetWhseBinAdapter(string whereClause, out System.Data.DataSet result) {
        result = null;
        bool result;    
        try 
        {           
            result = Ice.UI.FormFunctions.SearchFunctions.listLookup(this.oTrans, WhseBinAdapter, out result, true, whereClause);       
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // handle exceptions if any
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now with that, you can do something like this on your UI (partial code example) :

```
public class WarehouseBinSearchDialog
{
    private readonly WarehouseSearchService _warehouseSearchService = new WarehouseSearchService();
    private EpiTextBox myWhseBinSearchTextBox = null;

    private void ShowSearchDialog()
    {
        var binNumber = _warehouseSearchService.GetBinNumber();

        myWhseBinSearchTextBox.Text = binNumber.ToString();

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myWhseBinSearchTextBox.Text))
        {
            RefreshForm();
        }       
    }
}
```

when you separate the code, it will be easier to maintain and adapt for new changes.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment! In the Epicor environment, each form has the initialization and destruction methods as default. If I understand correctly, this custom code is just layer on top of the existing code. Within this layer is a mixture of the UI and business logic as you're observing. There are some other development areas within Epicor where I could possibly separate the business logic, and keep the UI components just on this form. Hmmm... I hadn't thought like this but now my brain is engaged after considering your suggestion. Thank you!